# How can i solve a "no method 'appendTo' error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I solve this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'appendTo'
in the following code :

```
    function refresh(){
        $('#contacts').empty();
        $( "#contactTmpl" ).tmpl( {contacts:contacts} ).appendTo( "#contacts" );
        $( ".contact" ).each( function(i) {
            var contact = contacts[i];
            $( "input.tomap", this ).link( contact );
        });
    }


 <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>

<form>
    <div id="contacts">Loading ...</div>
    <button class="add">New</button>
    <button class="save"> Save</button>
</form>
<script id="contactTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

    {{each contacts}}
        <div class="contact" data-index="${$index}">
            <label>First name</label> <input class="tomap" name="firstName" value="${firstName}">
            <label>Last name</label> <input class="tomap" name="lastName" value="${lastName}">
            <label>Number</label> <input class="tomap" name="phone" value="${phone}">
            <div class="tools">
                <button class="delete"</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

this is the html and javascript code

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've included here. WHen is refresh() getting called? After document ready or load, I hope. What is inside a.js? Maybe you could throw up a fiddle to look at?

Answer (score 4):

I going to assume you are using jQuery templates, since that is what it looks like.  If the template fails to render then it returns `null` which I believe is why you are getting the object has no method error.  I trimmed your code down to just the template and the call to render the template and fixed the `{{each}}` and the `${$index}`.  I also assume the variable `contacts` is an array of objects.

A working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/yfcuL/

Also the code:

```
<div id="contacts">EMPTY</div>
<script id="contactTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each(index,contact) contacts}}       
        <div class="contact" data-index="${index}">
            <label>First name</label> <input class="tomap" name="firstName" value="${contact.firstName}">
            <label>Last name</label> <input class="tomap" name="lastName" value="${contact.lastName}">
            <label>Number</label> <input class="tomap" name="phone" value="${contact.phone}">
            <div class="tools">
                <button class="delete"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>

$(function(){
    $( "#contactTmpl" ).tmpl( {contacts: contacts} ).appendTo( "#contacts" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the node first. Try this:

```
$('<div id="contactTmpl"/>').tmpl( {contacts:contacts} ).appendTo( "#contacts" );
```